# Dynamic Programming Problem for "disorder" in array

Tags: algorithm

Given a sequence a=(a1,a2....an) from n postive integers. We call Disorder D(ak) of ak=(a1,a2...ak) the diference between ak's max from ak's min. We call Total Disorder the sum all D(ak) for all subsequences from k=2 to k=n. We are looking for a dp algorithm with a recursive solution for b*, witch is a permutation of a,and it achieves minimum D(ak) from k=2 to k=n.

[image]

Exmples:
a=(6, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3) then b*=(3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 6)[with D(b*) = 0 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 5 = 8]

a=(1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6) then b*=(3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 1)[with D(b*) = 0 + 0 + 3 + 3 + 5 = 11]

The only thing i was able to prove was that at the end of b* the number will be either the max of a or min of a.

Pls help.

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: The dp algorithm in order to solve this problem.

Comment: "Disorder" is confusing, see [How to calculate entropy from a set of samples?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369743/how-to-calculate-entropy-from-a-set-of-samples)

Comment: Its not a global definition. Its a problems definition

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, questions, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Answer (score 1):

First sort the input array, and then consider building the result permutation backwards from the end towards the start.

For every element you will either remove the first or last element of the sorted array.  Also, for every position k, the disorder of the subarray ending at that position is known -- it's just the difference between the two ends of the remaining element array.

To find the optimal selection, then, you can use `DP[k,n]` = the minimum disorder so far if we've chosen n elements from the front of the sorted array (with the remainder chosen from the back).

`DP[k,n]` is easily calculated from `DP[k+1,n]` and `DP[k+1,n-1]`, and the minimum `DP[0,?]` is the minimum total disorder.

Comment: I think you have missed the Total Disorder...you say that the disorder of the position k is the difference between max and min. But in your dp you call disorder in a Totatl Disorder recursion. Total Disorder is the same as disorder but above all elements of the array.

Comment: But your answer gave me the help i needed to actually solve the problem...so thanks a lot!!!